# Each matrix element interact with each other

Tags: matrix

guys, i have the following matrix m[3][3] and i'd like to get the following result:

(0,0) * (0,1) 
(0,0) * (0,2) 
(0,0) * (1,0) 
(0,0) * (1,1) 
(0,0) * (1,2) 
(0,0) * (2,0) 
(0,0) * (2,1) 
(0,0) * (2,2) 


(0,1) * (0,2) 
(0,1) * (1,0) 
(0,1) * (1,1) 
(0,1) * (1,2) 
(0,1) * (2,0) 
(0,1) * (2,1) 
(0,1) * (2,2) 


until... 
(2,0) * (2,1) 
(2,0) * (2,2) 


(2,1) * (2,2)

Thank You !!!

Answer (score 0):

I have written this in C++ but I'm sure it is easy to port to any other language since I'm not using any special features.

I am not sure if it's the most effective way but this should sure do the trick.

```
for( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
{
    for( int j = i; j < 9; j++ )
    {
        int x0 = i % 3;
        int y0 = i / 3;

        int x1 = j % 3;
        int y1 = j / 3;

        if( x0 == x1 && y0 == y1 )
            continue;

        printf( "%i %i %i %i\n", y0, x0, y1, x1 );
    }
}
```

This problem is known as the handshake problem, every person in a room wants to shake hands with every other person in the room.

I had to add the if statement to prevent elements handshaking themselves.

Comment: i running that but i not sure, there is a combination of 9C2, and apparently the result should be 36, but it's 24.

Comment: No idea about your implementation and needs, although I'm pretty sure my output is correct, check it out here, http://pastebin.com/hJcbrhYF, it's exactly what you asked for.